# Statically allocating 2D array in C, why is it not working?

Tags: c

I need help figuring out why is this not working in C language.
My intention is to allocate statically two 2D array like this:

```
unsigned char raw_image2D[RAW_HEIGHT][RAW_WIDTH];
unsigned char raw_image2D_mirror[RAW_HEIGHT][RAW_WIDTH];
```

Where RAW_WIDTH and RAW_HEIGHT are defined as follows;

```
#define RAW_WIDTH 1600*3
#define RAW_HEIGHT 1200
```

Why is this not working, it compiles but at run time it breaks saying it is stack overflow?
Thank you

P.S. Why is this question so bad that you are giving a minuses?

**NOTE : Solved by adding static in front of array declaration.**
I will give points to that answer who suggested this solution, although others are possible but I need [][] annotation.

Comment: "it breaks" is not helpful; what is the exact symptom?

Comment: Please post some code. How would we know what's going wrong? Also, you don't need the extra ';' character at the end of raw_image2D .

Comment: stack overflow whn it breaks

Comment: Please post a complete "working" example. That is, it needs to be enough code to reproduce the exact problem which you are asking about. Also explain what happens when you compile and run it. Please include word-for-word error messages and output.

Comment: You'll probably get upvoted if you post the code that addresses this array.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus - other code is not exsisting, it is all I wrote in my program. If you like I can put main etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stack overflow. For example on some system the stack size per process is set to 4 Mo. `4800 * 1200` would be too much in that case (> 4 Mo).

Use an array with static storage duration or better, use `malloc` to allocate your array.

Comment: You have a <this site>-.com

Comment: How do you know it's on the stack ? He did say "statically".

Comment: @cnicutar I guessed that he used the word *statically* in the sense as: opposed to *dynamically*.

Comment: Technically, the stack is (kindof) statically allocated; you just carve it up at runtime.

Comment: Use an array with static storage duration? Can you explian

Comment: @AntunTun add the `static` specifier when you declare your array or declare the array at file-scope. But the preferable solution is to use `malloc` as there is no need to reserve all this memory for the lifetime of the program.

Comment: I know but I need [][] notation for my algorithm, it is easier to work with 2d notation then malloc, that is the reason I need it this way

Comment: @AntunTun You can use the same notation with a `malloc`ed array. You just have to use the right type. Read the questions to arrays of arrays in the c-faq: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: I have allocated huge memory arrays statically. I'd still like to see some code and more information that says what kind of processor this is. I'm not saying this answer is wrong, but I'd like to see more information.

Comment: @ouah I tried accessing malloced array but it says it expects another kind of notation

Comment: @octopusgrabbus this has nothing to do with the processor. On Linux check `ulimit -s` value to get the stack size per process. If the result is 8192 kB or less, having the two arrays in the stack (> 8 Mo) will get you trouble.